# Unity Performance - Coroutines vs FSM on update

Tags: unity-game-engine, coroutine, state-machine, fsm

I just started studying Unity scripting and I'm having a hard time to understand why some people prefer coroutines over state machines.

I do understand that the code might be more readable for some programmers, but I can't understand why some people say that using coroutines are preferable for performance.

I'm using C# in Unity, and from what I understand the [C# compiler converts the IEnumerator into a state machine](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter6/iteratorblockimplementation.aspx).

So maybe I'm missing something here. Is it better for runtime performance to use Coroutines instead of a FSM loop for handling behavior and states? If yes, why?

Comment: Well, coroutines *are* state machines (routines with state, basically), so how do you distinguish between them?

Comment: Thank you, Lex. Won't repeat that.

Comment: That's precisely my point Mehrdad, why are there people saying that coroutines are faster if its the same thing than writing a state machine on the update?

Comment: @Mehrdad I'd argue that coroutines are more like an _inline orchestration_ rather than a state machine with _obvious partitions_

Comment: @Hodor using a coroutine does not mean your code automatically runs faster.  I'd be more worried about the bad habbits it teaches c# developers over a method `yield`ing something that is never used

Answer (score 8):

Using coroutines is faster in some circumstances because you can conveniently schedule Unity to perform operations at certain intervals rather than doing them every frame, thus saving processing time. It's really the scheduling that saves time, not coroutines as such.

Take the example you highlighted (in you comment in the other answer) from the Unity documentation, where it says:

> Use Coroutines. The problem with Update calls is that they happen every frame. Quite possibly checking the distance to the player could be performed only every 5 seconds. This would save a lot of processing power.

This is saying that a coroutine that uses `WaitForSeconds( 5f )` will be faster then checking the distance every frame. It doesn't mean that doing so would necessarily be faster than having your own `Update` logic that only checks distance every five seconds.

Having said that, I wouldn't be surprised if the coroutine approach is still faster (though less dramatically so) than `Update`-based checking-every-five-seconds logic, because you'd still save on checking the current frame's time every frame in your game code. Yes, somewhere in Unity's engine loop this time check is still happening and being used to determine whether to go to the next coroutine step, but it's likely highly optimized and it's happening anyways, so the coroutine isn't adding as much extra time checking logic as the `Update`-based approach.

By the way, for a nice outline of how Unity is likely implementing coroutines, see this [blog post](http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2011/07/07/unity3d-coroutines-in-detail/).

Comment: Thanks, Ghopper! I was thinking in these lines. I wanted to know if there are any bottlenecks if we use a FSM inside the update calls on Unity.

Apparently, there aren't. As you said, and I agree, we can just control the frequency of time that a particular part of the code is being called inside the update function.

Comment: _"Using coroutines...faster ...some circumstances...schedule  at certain intervals rather  every frame"_ - incorrect.  I can make a **co-routine** that will **yield once per frame**. I can also make it perform **expensive distance** calculations **per yield** per frame.  Unity should be ashamed of that quote because such behaviour can only be accomplished if the coroutine had a time check, something that easily can be added to the Update code.  People need to stop believing this fallacy that using coroutines is an immediate boost to performance. Bad code happens anywhere.

Comment: By the way, do you know your 2nd last paragraph is a complete reversal and much clearer?  I'd give you a **+1** just for that :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful about what you're using coroutines for. They are great for long-running operations that you don't want to hang the game.

However you have to be very careful about how often you yield in the coroutine. Every time you yield, it takes some time (multiple frames) for the coroutine to resume. If you yield too much, your coroutine will be processing slower than it needs to be. For example, I was working on a pathfinding system. I was using a coroutine to periodically yield while it was running the pathfinding algorithm. This was causing the pathfinding code to take much longer than it should have. I found it worked much faster to just do it in Update.

Coroutines are nice for doing long-running asynchronous tasks like a web request, or downloading something in the background, etc. I don't know that I would recommend using coroutines for your main game processing loop. (especially for input)

Comment: That's a good insight, Phil. Have you tried to use C# async calls or maybe a custom FSM instead of co-routines for standalone behaviours?

Comment: I use Zenject for it's IoC container and dependency injection. I use FSMs for the "core" game loop stuff that needs to be done every frame. (FSM is updated in unity's standard Update loop). I use some coroutines for long-running asynchronous tasks, but not vanilla unity coroutines, I like UniRX for doing observable coroutines.

Comment: Sanity prevails! Great post. :)  There seems to be a culture (if SO posts are an indication) that coroutines are the be all and end all of update logic when a FSM is more than sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a universal answer to that. It very much depends on what you are doing in your code. A badly written Coroutine might be slower than a well-written FSM and vice versa. I'd say readability and understandability of your code always wins over potential (and at this state intanglible) performance gains. If you got a specific performance issue tackle it when you encounter it. So I'd suggest you use the approach that is most intuitive to you and your team.

Comment: Thank you, Jan. I do agree that there is no universal answer and that it really depends on how you write your code. For you to understand why I'm asking this, I've been reading some [forums posts](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/67856-Coroutines-vs-Update) where the users believe that Coroutines will be faster than having a loop on the update function. The [Unity Documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.Performance_Optimization.html) also says that using Coroutines is better for performance. However, the example they use can be done with FSM as well.

Comment: @Hodor - as far as I can see in the Unity documentation on performance optimization you linked to above, there's no mention of coroutines. Is that the right link?

Comment: @Ghopper: weird, the link is right. Check the 3rd part of section 5, the very last sentence before the end